# Как сделать переадресацию с короткого на обычный адрес url?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, .htaccess

Как сделать переадресацию с короткого адрес например: `site.com/74339` на обычный `site.com/ru/news/74339` без посторонних сайтов которые делают переадресацию. `74339` - это id новостей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В каждом фреймворке это делается немного по-разному, но в целом суть такая:

Вам нужно обрабатывать новый тип url`s, которые содержат в себе только число. Т.е. добавляете route вроде такого:

```
'news_short_link' => array(
    'url' => '/\d+',
    'controller' => 'Controller_News',
    'action' => 'shortLink',
)
```

А в обработчике, т.е. в нужном контроллере, проверяете по базе есть ли у вас в базе новость с такой id:

1. Если есть, то делаете редирект (можно 301) на url новости. 301 - постоянный редирект - браузеры его запоминают и при последующих обращениях будут сразу запрашивать целевой url. Пример редиректа на нативном php:

```
header('Location: http://site.com/ru/news/' . $id);
```

Во фреймворках обычно уже есть более удобные обёртки для редиректов, но по сути все они выполняют такой же редирект.

2. Если id в базе нет, то возвращаете ошибку 404.

В общем, настраивайте редирект с короткого адреса на полный, на php:

```
if (preg_match('@^/(?<id>\d+)$@', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches)) { // если url состоит только из числа
    $id = $matches[0];
    $news = Table_News::me()->selectRowById($id); // ищем в БД новость с таким id

    if ($news) { // если новость найдена, перенаправляем на целевой url
        header('Location: http://site.com/ru/news/' . $id);
    }
}
```

Пример редиректа на nginx:

```
location ~ /(\d+)$ {
    return 301 http://site.com/ru/news/$1;
}
```

Comment: Я пишу сайт с нуля не могли бы вы более подробно объяснить. Спасибо.

Comment: @Muson А вы для начала лучше бы показали как вы обрабатываете такие urls site.com/ru/news/74339 ? т.е. вообще как определяете какой контент отдавать, т.к. вариантов уйма.

Comment: Думаю, что преобразование site.com/74339 в site.com/ru/news/74339 можно сделать на чистом реврайте в .htaccess, без нагрузки в виде php.

Comment: @Visman да, вы правы, можно и через .htaccess. Или на nginx rewrite. Будет лучше по производительности.

Comment: Дополните свой ответ, пожалуйста ;)

Comment: @Visman для nginx добавил, а в .htaccess я не сильно разбираюсь, у меня и apache не установлен. Если что, вы добавляйте :)